# moving many sprites at a time without using scheduler

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i m developing an application. In which i have to move sprites on click event. problem is i have to move 2-3 images at a time on click n also check collision. so i created class of that sprites n wrote moving functions as member function. but i m not able to use scheduler in that file. so its again move 1 sprite at a time. so i want to write generalized code for moving sprites without using scheduler. so can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

you could try a runAction method with duration.